# Deserialize objects with RestSharp where the class is in a type attribute

Tags: c#, xml, rest, deserialization, restsharp

I'm trying to consume data from a rest api.
I need to deserialize objects from a rest API using RestSharp.
The all objects in lists are an "object" element where the object's class is the value of a "type" attribute.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
<list>
    <object type="cat">
        <id>107</id>
        <name>Garry</name>
    </object>
    <object type="dog">
        <id>83</id>
        <name>Fluffy</name>
    </object>
</list>
```

And partially implemented classes for the example:

```
public class Animal
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[DeserializeAs(Name = "cat")]
public class Cat : Animal
{
}

[DeserializeAs(Name = "dog")]
public class Dog : Animal
{
}
```

It seems like the wrong way to go, but tried defining all of my classes using the attribute:

```
[DeserializeAs(Name = "object")]
```

This allows them to deserialize properly, as long as I know what type of object to expect in the list, and obviously the list only contains one type of object.

The problem comes in if I get a list containing different types of objects.

Is there a way to handle this well using the standard deserializer?
If not, I am open to ways to handle this effectively with a large number of different object types.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the standard deserializer. I am pretty sure it was not designed to handle this. I ended up making my own fork.

I added another attribute for describing the object in lists:

```
[DeserializeElementAs(Name = "", Attribute = "", Value = "")]
```

The attribute name might not be the best, but I was not sure what to call it.

So the classes for the xml from the question would be defined as:

```
public class Animal
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[DeserializeElementAs(Name = "object", Attribute = "type", Value = "cat")]
[DeserializeAs(Name = "cat")]
public class Cat : Animal
{
}

[DeserializeElementAs(Name = "object", Attribute = "type", Value = "dog")]
[DeserializeAs(Name = "dog")]
public class Dog : Animal
{
}
```

I posted the code of fork to github if anyone else needs it.

https://github.com/comless/RestSharp/commit/1fea0fd97cadc7035dbea99c17b7423ca14b5267